# how to load a large number of txt-files into a hashmap in java

Tags: java

I've got a folder with a large quantity of txt-files on my harddisk. I am looking for a method to load those txt-files into a hashmap, where the filename is the key (as string) and the filecontent is the corresponding value (as string). How can i do that automatically, for the entire folder content?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: There's no way to do it automatically. You have to code to do it.

Comment: How many files? How big is each?

Comment: Hint : take a look at `Files.walkFileTree()`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class, especially the `File.listFiles()` (lists all the files in a directory) and `isDirectory` method. Recursively go into folders by checking `File.isDirectory()` and use `File.getName()` to get the name, and an `FileReader` to read the content.

Some pseudocode:

```
Map<String, String> fileMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
public void visitFiles(File folder) {
    for each file f in folder
        if 
            f is directory then visitFiles(f)
        else 
            use FileReader to read into buffer String
            add filename and buffer to map        
}
```

Comment: Since Java 7, the OP can use `Files.walkFileTree().`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to load all of your contents to a map.
If you have plenty of files and large contents, it will be a waste of the memory, and it is easy to cause OOM.
Try using guava to deal with files.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for every answer. I've got 2000 txt-files, that i would like to use as trainingdata for a support vector machine (svmlight). to do the nessessary preprocessing (vectorizing, tf-idf weighting, etc.), i would like to use a small java programm. I already have most of the code i need from a previous project of mine. however, since i had only a handfull of files to process then, i was just writing every single filename into the code. obviously, thats not possible for 2000 files, so i am looking for an alternative.